# How to concatenate all the child nodes in an Xelement?

Tags: xml, linq

I have the xml in the following format  :

```
<parent>
          <child id="1"> test1 </child>
          <child id="2"> test2 </child>
</parent>
```

How can I get the csv of all the childnodes ? Like , this is how I need it :

```
<parent>
          <children>1|test1;2|test2</children>
</parent>
```

where | and ; are delimiters.

Any suggestions how it can be done using LINQ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var xml = @"<parent>
                <child id=""1""> test1 </child>
                <child id=""2""> test2 </child>
        </parent>";
XElement parentElement = XElement.Parse(xml);
var childElements = parentElement.Elements("child").ToList();
var concatenatedValue = string.Join(";", childElements.Select(c => c.Attribute("id").Value + "|" +c.Value).ToArray());
childElements.ForEach(c => c.Remove());
parentElement.Add(new XElement("child", concatenatedValue));

var newXml = parentElement.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File.WriteAllText("C:\\myText.csv",
    "<parent><children>" +
    String.Join(";",
        XDocument.Load("C:\\my.xml").Descendants("child")
        .Select(e => e.Attribute("id") + "|" + e.Value)) + 
    "</children></parent");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
XDocument inDoc = XDocument.Parse(
    "<parent><child id='1'>test1</child><child id='2'>test2</child></parent>");
XDocument outDoc = XDocument.Parse(
    String.Format("<parent><children>{0}</children></parent>",
        String.Join(";",
            inDoc.Root.Elements()
            .Select(e => e.Attribute("id").Value + "|" + e.Value)
            .ToArray())));
```

Comment: Why use something as expensive as String.Format for a simple concatenation?

Comment: Just because it made the example cleaner since it isolates the Linq part at the end of the expression. Notice I used simple concat inside where I'm joining the attribute and element values. You can obviously use concat for the outer content too - it just didn't make it quite as obvious what was going on (at least to me).